# adding helicopter video files to Google Earth or QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-earth, helicopter, video

Is it possible to add a helicopter's video files to Google Earth or QGIS ? 
We have a flight path points derived from the xml file associated with the .mpg file which I envision being used to pilot the video.
The .mpg files range in size 100mb to 2gb.

Comment: Do you want to start a video, after click on a point? If so you can use an QGIS Action, if you have a column in the point table with a filepath to the video.

Comment: Was thinking of having the video open in a separate window in Google Earth (or QGIS) while the view correspondingly flies where the video was taken. Which "QGIS Action" are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

An action runs a command, that in your case will open a movie player in a separate window, not a window embedded in QGIS, when you click on a point.

Actions for a layer are set under Properties > Actions. Look at some of the default actions; There is a button for the default sample actions coming with QGIS.

You will need a column with the filepath to the video.

Check some of the many tutorial on the net for QGIS actions:

http://dragons8mycat.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/gis-quick-tip-create-an-action-in-qgis/

...

Comment: This example using a wiki page is interesting:  http://linfiniti.com/2012/03/a-python-layer-action-to-open-a-wikipedia-page-in-qgis/

Comment: Couldn't find any examples on using video just one using a wiki page which is interesting:  http://linfiniti.com/2012/03/a-python-layer-action-to-open-a-wikipedia-page-in-qgis/

Comment: If it is a video, pdf, txt or what ever, it's the same procedure. Have a reference in a column to the file like D:\temp\myvideo.mpg. There is a default action call 'Open file' that you can use to compose your own video starter action.

Answer (score 1):

Does this QGIS plugin do something *along the lines* of what you are looking for?

**[Video UAV Tracker](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Video_UAV_Tracker/)** ([sourceforge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/videouavtrackerqgisplugin) and [description](http://sourceforge.net/projects/videouavtrackerqgisplugin/files/?source=navba))

Comment: This!!!!!!!!!!!